# Can't retrieve data attributes from HTML generated by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to retrieve the data- attributes on button on HTML that was loaded from JQuery, I know this causes issues.

I can get the button click to register however I can not access any of the attributes.

```
$(document).on("click", ".reportRequest", function(e){
    console.log($(e.relatedTarget).data("ip"));
});
```

Here is the javascript  and it returns undefined even though when I can see in inspect element that the button has assigned values

The HTML of the button is:

```
<button title="Report Request" class="btn btn-info pull-right reportRequest" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#shoutoutReportModal" data-ip="127.0.0.1" data-id="52"><i class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

I believe  the issue is because the HTML is generated on page load with an AJAX request.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: try with `e.target` instead of `e.relatedTarget`

Comment: From the jQuery docs: [`.relatedTarget`](https://api.jquery.com/event.relatedTarget/) -> _"The **other DOM element involved** in the event, if any."_ - What other element should be involved in clicking a button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try by using `$(this)`

```
$(document).on("click", ".reportRequest", function(e){
    console.log($(this).data("ip"));
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much